# APNS feedback 149 mean?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, feedback

I have implemented **APNS** code in my app.
It was working fine in **Development** build.

While in **production** build,
Device token is entered in database at server side, but none of the device is getting push notification.

At server side, in **PHP code**, **feedback response** is **149**,

I know this table,

```
0 - No errors encountered

1 - Processing error

2 - Missing device token

3 - Missing topic

4 - Missing payload

5 - Invalid token size

6 - Invalid topic size

7 - Invalid payload size

8 - Invalid token

255 - None (unknown)
```

But how to read **149** in this table???? Which entity to compare? I am sending content along with message, so it should not be **"4 - Missing payload".**

Comment: What methods do you have in your app delegate, that should process the received push notification payload?

Comment: @luke i am using `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` to receive notification.

Comment: It has to be about distribution/development provision profile against the production pem file.

Comment: @RenoJones I am using different ck.pem for development and production. I am using the one i have created with production profile.

Comment: @HinataHyuga Ok, but what do you have inside that method? Does it get hit? Is there an NSError that you can call the description/localizedDescription method on?

Comment: No, above method is used to received remote push notifications if application is open.

Comment: @this error i am getting for production profile. So, i can't see that. Right now just trying to figure out where that error is. In PHP, i am getting feedback 149. How to know what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was some error from server side. It's working perfectly now without changing anything in code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use also the production Server from apple with you PHP - Script?
Production server:
 - gateway.push.apple.com 2195
instead of development server
 - gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195